# Can’t identify this character

Tags: characters, traditional-characters

I have tried a usually effective OCR on it, and tried imitating the appearance in a handwriting recognizer, but neither gives anything that seems possibly correct.  If context helps, it is preceded by  樂.  The editing was to hide confusing background from the OCR.
[image]

Comment: Possible 園 in a cursive font.

Comment: Given the context, this is probably the answer.  Want to re-enter it as such?  The waitress said it was correct, but I got the impression that she is third-generation and may not know.  (Her Spanish sounded native.)  It looked clearer on the menu with no sign of a box, but neither OCR nor imitation came up with anything.  The Spanish name of the restaurant translates to “Peking Palace.”

Comment: Her Spanish sounded native doesn't give any information about her Chinese. As far as I know, OCR can't handle such cursive font, especially when bold, most strokes just get merged.

Comment: She also didn’t seem to notice when I said 谢谢.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede que es 樂園 （乐园）: el paraíso

Answer (score 0):

definitely 园 (walled garden, now just garden)